# should std::common_type use std::decay?

Tags: c++, c++11, conditional-operator, type-traits, lvalue

Given types `A,B`, I am concerned with the exact definition of `std::common_type<A,B>`, disregarding the variadic case `std::common_type<A...>` for arbitrary types `A...`. So let

```
using T = decltype(true ? std::declval<A>() : std::declval<B>());
using C = std::common_type<A,B>;
```

Now, according to a number of sources, I have found the following relations (skipping `typename` for brevity):

- [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/common_type):  `C::type = std::decay<T>::type`
- [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/type_traits/common_type/):  `C::type = T`
- GCC 4.8.1 `<type_traits>` implementation:  `C::type = std::decay<T>::type` if `T` is valid, otherwise `C` does not contain a `::type` member ("SFINAE-friendly")
- Clang 3.3 `<type_traits>` implementation:  `C::type = std::remove_reference<T>::type`

I find the "SFINAE-friendly" version of GCC a minor detail, while `std::remove_reference` and `std::decay` practically only differ in built-in arrays and functions, plus cv-qualification, for which again I am not concerned much. So my question is

**Should it be `decay<T>::type` or just `T`? What is the rationale of using `decay<T>::type`? Is it only about representing result `A() + B()` e.g. for arithmetic expressions?**

For instance, experimenting a bit, I have found that in the case of the "just `T`" definition, we have

```
common_type<int&,int&> = int&
common_type<int&,long&> = long
```

that is, *an lvalue reference is maintained if types are equal*. This reflects the fact that

```
int a, b;
(true ? a : b) = 0;
```

is valid, while

```
int a;
long b;
(true ? a : b) = 0;
```

is not. This semantics of "allowing assignment if types are equal" is exactly what I need in one application, and I tend to believe that `common_type` and `decay` should be two independent steps. Should I just use my own definitions?

Comment: `remove_reference` and `decay` also differ in the cv-qualification for reference types; `std::declval<A>` returns an rvalue reference.

Comment: `T` is old (C++11), `decay<T>` is new (C++1y), there's probably a defect related to this. Let me see..

Comment: @dyp Yes, I wasn't so careful there, that's why I wrote "practically", I'll fix.

Comment: Here it is: http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/lwg-defects.html#2141

Comment: If you need the correct value category, I'd write my own `common_type_valcat` *based upon* `common_type` (as `common_type` might have been specialized by someone).

Comment: @dyp The problem is that, according to your answer, all specializations should be supposed to use `decay` as well, after which it's too late to recover the original type given by the ternary operator... Now it seems like a mess to me.

Comment: Yeah, if you need a version that can unify identical lvalue reference types as still references, it's probably best to write your own.

Comment: @iavr The simplest thing to do is if the types are all lvalue references, return `typename std::common_type<Types...>::type &` (i.e., add an lvalue reference). However, this isn't enough because of cv-qualification and it gets more complicated once you have types like `struct foo { operator int&(); };` that can be converted from a prvalue `foo` to an lvalue `int`.

Comment: Yes, it does get complicated, especially with `foo`. E.g. given `foo f;` you can say `++f;` but not `f = 0;`. Besides this case, I am more inclined to just removing rvalue-references (caused by `declval` or not) and leaving cv-qualification intact. Anyhow, I'll see how it goes with my application.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> should std::common_type use std::decay?

Yes, see [Library Working Group Defect #2141](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/lwg-defects.html#2141).

Short version (long version, see link above):

- `declval<A>()` returns a `A&&`
- `common_type` is specified via `declval`, n3337:

  ```
  template <class T, class U>
  struct common_type<T, U> {
      typedef decltype(true ? declval<T>() : declval<U>()) type;
  };
  ```
- `common_type<int, int>::type` therefore yields `int&&`, which is unexpected
- proposed resolution is to add `decay`

  ```
  template <class T, class U>
  struct common_type<T, U> {
      typedef decay_t < decltype(true ? declval<T>() : declval<U>()) > type;
  };
  ```
- `common_type<int, int>::type` now yields `int`

Comment: Hmm... that shows indeed how we ended up in using `decay`, so it answers the question, thanks a lot. Too bad however, I now have to use my own definitions... Yes, `<int,int>` should give `int` and not `int&&`, but `<int&,int&>` should give `int&` for me. So only additional `&&` added by `declval` should be removed.

Comment: @iavr The discussion at the LWG page contains *"Users of `common_type` do not expect to get a reference type as the result"* Not sure who *the users* are, though.

Comment: Well, not me for sure :-)

Comment: Bah, I expected to get a reference if I feed in references, and I'm a user of `common_type`.  If I want to implement the equivalent of a many-argument chained `?`, `common_type` now behaves fundamentally differently, and as `common_type` is the only spot where one expects specialization of things like `std::chrono` and other extensions, one can no longer implement a many-argument chained `?`.

Comment: Ok, I can do binary `common_type` to access said overloads, strip references coming in and add them coming out, and use my own unary and trinary+ implementations for those cases, so this can be recovered from.

Comment: I just landed here cause I expected common_type<int&, int&> to return an int&. It returned an int, my code silently compiled, and a test failed. Been debugging this for a bit already... lucky I had a test.

Comment: @Yakk I also do not know why you would expect `common_type_t<X&, X&>` to *not* yield `X&`, when that's what the conditional operator would yield...

Comment: @Barry I expect it to yield `X&`, but the standard disagrees.  As far as I can tell, this is because the standard added an over-zealous `decay` when it should have added a `remove_reference_if_rvalue_reference` or somesuch.  (`decltype(  false?0:0.0 )` evaluates to a `double&&` not a `double`, and whomever added `decay` thought this was surprising and avoided by a `decay`)