# Why is `std::common_type_t<std::ostream &, std::ostream &>` equal to `std::ostream` and not `std::ostream &`?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, stl, template-meta-programming

I'm working on a small library, and one of the things I need to do is apply visitors to some data and return the results.

In some older C++ code, visitors were expected to declare a `typedef return_type`. For instance, `boost::static_visitor` does that.

In newer code, all those visitors are deprecated. In C++14 you can usually use `decltype(auto)`, but I'm trying to do it using something like `std::common_type` so that I can do it in C++11.

I tried simply backporting an example implementation of `std::common_type` to C++11 and using that to figure out return types.

However I get some unexpected results when using the "possible implementation" on [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/common_type)

```
#include <ostream>
#include <type_traits>

// decay_t backport

template <typename T>
using decay_t = typename std::decay<T>::type;

// common_type backport

template <typename T, typename... Ts>
struct common_type;

template <typename T>
struct common_type<T> {
  using type = decay_t<T>;
};

template <typename T1, typename T2>
struct common_type<T1, T2> {
  using type = decay_t<decltype(true ? std::declval<T1>() : std::declval<T2>())>;
};

// TODO: Is this needed?
/*
template <typename T>
struct common_type<T, T> {
  using type = T;
};
*/

template <typename T1, typename T2, typename T3, typename... Ts>
struct common_type<T1, T2, T3, Ts...> {
  using type = typename common_type<typename common_type<T1, T2>::type, T3, Ts...>::type;
};

template <typename T, typename... Ts>
using common_type_t = typename common_type<T, Ts...>::type;

// static_assert(std::is_same<common_type_t<std::ostream &, std::ostream &>, std::ostream &>::value, "This is what I expected!");
static_assert(std::is_same<common_type_t<std::ostream &, std::ostream &>, std::ostream>::value, "Hmm...");

int main() {}
```

What "should" the result of `std::common_type_t<std::ostream&, std::ostream&>` be? Should it not be `std::ostream &`? If not, then why do both `gcc 5.4.0` and `clang 3.8.0` think it is `std::ostream`?

Note: When I use the "real" `std::common_type_t` in C++14, I still get `std::ostream` and not `std::ostream &`.

Is specializing `std::common_type` so that `std::common_type_t<T, T>` is always `T` a valid approach? It seems to work well in my program, but it feels like a hack.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/21975812/2069064, but yeah `common_type` doesn't give you references because sad face.

Comment: Thank you... so I guess I should not use `std::declval` there? Should I use `decltype(true ? std::forward<T1>(std::declval<T1>()) : std::forward<T2>(std::declval<T2>()))` ? I guess this is actually pretty tricky...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21975812/2069064) for related discussion on the history around `common_type` and why it doesn't actually yield a reference.

> Is specializing `std::common_type` so that `std::common_type_t<T, T>` is always T a valid approach?

I assume you mean specializing *your* implementation of `common_type` (since you can't specialize the other one). And no, that isn't sufficient. You probably want `common_type<Base&, Derived&>` to be `Base&`, but that instantiation won't go through your specialization.

What you really want is to *not* use `decay`. The reason the `decay` is in there is to drop the surprise rvalue reference that `declval` provides in some cases. But you want to maintain the lvalue reference - so just add your own type trait:

```
template <class T>
using common_decay_t = std::conditional_t<
    std::is_lvalue_reference<T>::value,
    T,
    std::remove_reference_t<T>>;
```

And use that instead of the normal `decay`.

Comment: I guess I'm working with this version for now, marking your answer as correct though: `template <class T>
using mini_decay_t = conditional_t<
    std::is_lvalue_reference<T>::value,
    T,
    decay_t<T>>;
`